# Save input as text file in python

Tags: python, input, save

I got a simple python code with some inputs where a user has to type name, age, player name and his best game.
Now I want that all these inputs from the user were saved as a text file or something like this.

I tried

```py
with open ("Test_", "a") as file:
    User_input = file.write(input("here type in your name"))
```

I tried it with `with open ...` n where I create a new text file before which I open in python and add something. But everything I tried failed. Hope my English is good enough to understand what kind of problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

OUTFILE = 'gameplayers.csv'


def main():
    player = []
    morePlayer = 'y'
    while morePlayer == 'y':
        name = input('Enter your name: ')
        age = input('Your age: ')
        playerName = input('Your player name: ')
        bestGame = input('What is your best game: ')
        player.append([name, age, playerName, bestGame])
        morePlayer = input('Enter information of more players: (y, n): ')

    with open(OUTFILE, 'a', encoding='utf_8') as f:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        csvWriter.writerows(player)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: great thank you :-) this looks good and works :-) how can i solve it that all inputs are not in one field ? i mean that name is in one field , age is in one field and so on ? with this code is it actualy all in one field

Comment: @Julian90 Yes, one can code it, so all the inputs are in a single field, separated by, say, a comma, but separating them into different fields is the usual way.

Comment: @Julian90 Could you kindly click the Up arrow (which means 'This answer is useful') by the top left corner of my answer block, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know the difference between `'a'` and `'w'` in `with open`. `'w'` stands for write, meaning every time you call it, it will be overwritten. `'a'` stands for append, meaning new information will be appended to the file. In your case, I would have written the code something like this

```
userInput = input(“Enter your name: “)
with open(“filename.txt”, “a”) as f:
    f.write(userInput)
```

If you instead want to overwrite every time - change the `'a'` to a `'w'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep adding new data, use `a` otherwise, use `w` to overwrite. I've used `a` in this example:

```
name = input('Name: ')
age = input('Age: ')
best_game = input('Best Game: ')

with open('user_data.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f'Name: {name} - Age: {age} - Best Game: {best_game}\n')
```