# Save a list to a .txt file and keep them

Tags: python, save, txt

I found a way to print the list to a txt file, and it worked for me. Except for one detail,

```py
with open("data.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(list))
```

When I make a different data entry, new data replaces the old data I entered, I want it not to delete the old data and continue recording new data.

Comment: Use 'a' instead of 'w', eg. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp or [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the `open` function? What does it say happens when you pass `"w"`? Also, it *really* isn't clear what you *expect* to happen.

Comment: Fundamentally, though, `output.write(str(list))` is probably not very useful, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MyWork don't link to w3schools. It's not a great resource, and why would you? This is all in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan because that site is notorious for wildly incorrect explanations. In any case, it is merely repeating what is *already documented in the official documentation*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save input as text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019098/save-input-as-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `"w"` in the open function will rewrite the complete file so use `"a"` in the open function which will append the file and you will not lose the original text in the file